# check empty text

Tags: jquery

i have statement like this

```
var a = $("#txt1").val().trim()
```

how should check if 'a' is not empty

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
if (a) { /* a is not empty */ }
```

should do the trick, perhaps unless a contains "false" (not sure of that) but I suppose you could do

```
if (a !== null && a.length != 0) { /* a is not empty */ }
```

Comment: +1 for the second example. It's more robust and will work even with "false" in the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a !== null) {
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
if(a != '') {
  // alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( a !== "" ) { }
```